# Double quotes change into &quot; in Tiny MCE editor in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, wysiwyg, static-content

In Tiny MCE editor on a product page in M2.3, all my double quotes are changed into `&quot;` after saving.
Example:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url=&quot;contact&quot;}}">
```

This breaks the links on the page.

Is it possible to avoid this in an easy way e.g. by an admin setting?
Anybody knows of an editor extension that does the job properly?

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes inside of double quotes will result in `&quot;`. The most simple way to fix this, would be replacing the double quotes by single quotes.
Such as

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='contact'}}">
```

will work

Comment: It's NOT working.
This is what Tiny MCE makes of single quotes:
https://example.com/%E2%80%99contact%E2%80%99
What works however, is when I omit the (single or double) quotes like this:
<a href="{{store direct_url=contact}}">
Anybody who is able to explain?

Comment: still working for my side, when i place it in single quotes. The link links me to example.com/index.php/contact  (magento 2.3.2)

Comment: Any idea why it is only working without any quotes at my side?

Comment: no idea. i tried different ways to add links in cms pages and i am using a plain magento 2.3.2 installation without additional modules. Except of the sampeldata modules. Maybe something changed to 2.3.3, which version are you using ?

Comment: I am on 2.3.0. And I am trying to achieve the above in a product page. Not a CMS page.

Comment: actually it seems like there is an open issue for something similar: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19737

Comment: I have noticed. I will post there as well because it is all about the double quotes. Which should be single quotes, as you have pointed out correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100429/discussion-between-els-den-iep-and-ekk4rd).

Answer (score 0):

Elaborate answer including solution:

From Magento docs: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/markup-tags-links.html

> When used with an anchor tag, the markup tag is placed inside the
> double quotes of the anchor. To avoid confusion, you can alternate
> using single-and double quotes for each nested set of quotes.

Example WITH forward slash at the end, so additional references can be appended as a path.

```
<a href="{{store url='apparel/shoes'}}">Shoe Sale</a>
```

Example resulting in frontend url WITHOUT trailing slash:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='contact'}}">Contact Form</a>
```

However, It's NOT working in our case.

This is what Tiny MCE makes of single quotes:
http://example.com/%E2%80%99contact%E2%80%99

***Solution:*** What works however, is when I omit the (single or double) quotes like this:

`<a href="{{store direct_url=contact}}">`

Although Magento recommends single quotes, this works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I have found this solution by myside, with the help of this, atleast CMS changes will not get removed.

[WYSIWYG editor inserting &quot; instead of correct " in 2.3.0 when we use any anchor tags](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/279995/wysiwyg-editor-inserting-quot-instead-of-correct-in-2-3-0-when-we-use-any-an?answertab=votes#298392)

Comment: I have checked. Simply not using the wysiwyg editor is not considered to be a solution.